# Is there a laravel built-in way to run a seeder only once just like you can do with migrations using a migrations table?

Tags: php, laravel

Our team wants to be able to use seeders and run the seed command in our pipeline, however we don't want to run the seeders every time we deploy, only once in many cases so the data is there and doesn't get duplicated.

Is there a built in way within laravel to only run a seeder once and track its history, similar to migrations?

If not, our team will have to implement this ourselves with a seeders table and history functionality.

Comment: No, there is no built-in tracking for the seeds.

Comment: The way I've done this is to query the database for records in the table you're seeding, and only run the seeder if it's empty, something like `UsersSeeder.php` checking `if(User::exists()) { return false; }` (or similar). I don't know of a built-in way to ignore seeders once they've been run, but that's generally due to Seeders only ever being run once, i.e. typical deploy command is `php artisan migrate`, not `php artisan migrate --seed`, etc. (Mimicking the `migrations` table for Seeders is a cool idea too that should work)

Comment: Depends on what you're doing, but you could run a seeder from a migration (point). Also, instead of using a seeder component, you could put the entire seeder part in a migration.

Answer (score 8):

Call the seeder from a migration, and make sure **NOT** to reference it in `DatabaseSeeder` (`database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php`):

`database/migrations/2022_01_19_seedmytable.php`:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

class SeedMyTable extends Migration {
    public function up() {
        Artisan::call('db:seed', [
            '--class' => \SampleDataSeeder::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Do it as its own migration (recommended), or you can also tack the `Artisan::call('db:seed', ... )` bit onto the end of another [new] multi-purpose migration. Don't add to an existing migration script or it won't be guaranteed to run.

### TMTOWTDI

You can also just manually add a bunch of `MyModelClass::create(...)` statements at the end of the migration's `up()` method.

```php
<?php

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class SeedMyTable extends Migration {
    public function up() {
        // ... [imagine table creation statements here] ...
        User::create(['name' => 'Bob']);
        User::create(['name' => 'Alice']);
    }
}
```

You could also just log into the appropriate environment and the `artisan` command as-needed:

```bash
$ artisan db:seed --class=SampleDataSeeder
```

Comment: Yep, this. Or run the seeding in the migration itself; that'll allow you to make a `down()` migration too that undoes the seeding.

Answer (score 0):

Install [`ranium/laravel-seedonce`](https://github.com/ranium/laravel-seedonce) package.

Use `Ranium\SeedOnce\Traits\SeedOnce` trait in your desired DatabaseSeeder and run the seeder command.